# Discrepancy in Tensorflow outputs about GPU connectivities

Tags: amazon-ec2, tensorflow, gpu

I'm running TensorFlow v1.1 on EC2 with the p2.16xlarge instance. There are 16 GPUs and according to TensorFlow:

`2017-05-11 21:47:02.377465: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377490: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377510: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 1:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377525: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 2:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 3:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377551: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 4:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377563: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 5:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377575: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 6:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377588: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 7:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377598: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 8:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377611: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 9:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377624: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 10:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377639: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 11:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377653: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 12:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377666: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 13:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377680: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 14:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2017-05-11 21:47:02.377693: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 15:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y`

this seems to suggest that all 16 GPUs are connected via DMA.

However the same TensorFlow session also outputs the following:

`2017-05-11 21:47:02.183989: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 0 and 9
2017-05-11 21:47:02.184318: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 0 and 10
2017-05-11 21:47:02.184574: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 0 and 11
2017-05-11 21:47:02.184833: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 0 and 12
2017-05-11 21:47:02.185090: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 0 and 13
2017-05-11 21:47:02.185342: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 0 and 14
2017-05-11 21:47:02.185594: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 0 and 15
2017-05-11 21:47:02.207203: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 1 and 9
2017-05-11 21:47:02.207465: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 1 and 10
2017-05-11 21:47:02.207744: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 1 and 11
2017-05-11 21:47:02.208002: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 1 and 12
2017-05-11 21:47:02.208266: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 1 and 13
2017-05-11 21:47:02.208510: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 1 and 14
2017-05-11 21:47:02.208759: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 1 and 15
2017-05-11 21:47:02.228929: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:772] Unable to enable peer access between device ordinals 2 and 9
...`

which seems to suggest that the GPUs 1-9 and GPUs 10-16 are *not* connected. Which output is correct? Or am I just interpreting this wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There are some funny things going on with 16 GPU configuration, see this issue -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5789

Comment: I suggest that the Github issue is the right place to discuss this.